# Drawing a phase diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am working through an example to draw a phase diagram the DE used is
$\frac{dx}{dt}=xy(x-1)(x-y)$

In the first step I have to identify the isoclines by setting $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ having done this I found $x=0, y=0, x=1$ and $y=x$ this is obviously the $x$ axis, $y$ axis, a horizontal line $x=1$ and a line through the origin with slope 1

In the next step I am to identify the sign on both sides of this lines and insert direction arrows but I do not understand how to do this, and in the solution the line $y=x$ is not included. Any assistance please.

Comment: You're plotting $x$ vs $y$, or $t$ vs $x$?

Comment: You have not described the dynamics of $y$.

Comment: @ GFauxPass It seems for the example the plot is $x$ vs $y$ and at CTNT there was no equation given for $\frac{dy}{dt} this is the intoductory example to the chapter why such a complex one was chosen I do not know

Comment: Well you cannot design the phase diagram if you do not have function $g(x,y)$ defined from $\frac{dy}{dt}=g(x,y)$ unless $y$ is a constant and in that case the phase diagram is defined on a line.